# Send push notification containing a base64 image using FCM and firebase cloud functions

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to send a push notification after an element is created on a specific node of my database. I am using **firebase cloud functions**, **firebase cloud messaging** and ionic client app. I want to include a **base64 image in the notification's body**.
here is the code of the  function deployed on firebase sever.

```
exports.addItem = functions.database.ref('/products/categoriy01/{itemid}')

.onCreate( event=>{

   const product=event.data.val();

   admin.messaging().sendToTopic('all',{

       'notification':{
           title:"My app name",
           body : "A new available product "+product.picture
        }
    })
  }
);
```

The function is correctly deployed on the server.
In the above code, the **picture property** of **the product object** is in **base64 format**. **What i want is to convert that image before sending the push notification.** So it will  enable the users to see the product picture in the notification.

Any help ? Thanks.

Comment: you should be sending the image url in the payload and download on client side. You should not be encoding and the image. Also if you didn't know payload limit is 4kb

Comment: you can only send 4k of data in a push message so you will not be able to send a whole image

Comment: @UmangChamaria does it means that the image can be displayed only after the click on the notification ? when  the page describing the products is displayed ?

Comment: @tyczj thank you for your contribution.

Comment: No it doesn't, I am not sure how you are handling push display on the client side. Sharing client side handling would help here